# Самописный chmod

Tags: winapi, c, chmod

Доброго времени суток.
По учебе задали написать аналог утилиты chmod под Windows на Си.
Но есть проблема.
chmod назначает права для владельца, группы владельца и остальных пользователей.
Но что есть группа владельца? Если владелец состоит в нескольких группах, какая группа нужна?

И главное - какой функцией WinAPI можно получить эту группу?

Еще вопрос. 
Функция [GetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645(v=vs.85).aspx) может вернуть:

> ppsidGroup [out, optional]
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives
> a pointer to the primary group SID

Что это за primary group? Это и есть группа владельца?
Назначая этой группе права, SID этой группы определяется как "None".
Будет здорово, если ответите хоть на один вопрос.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Система прав в Windows и *nix довольно сильно отличается.

В *nix у каждого файла есть 2 значение - владелец-пользователь и владелец-группа, причем пользователь не обязательно должен состоять в группе владельца файла.

chmod устанавливает 9 значений. 3 права (rwx) на юзера-владельца, группу владельца, всех остальных.

В Windows используются списки прав. У файла есть 1 владелец + список прав. Каждый элемент списка - это настройка прав для какой-то сущности (пользователь или группа). Соответственно Windows позволяет задать права одновременно многим пользователям и группам.

В общем случае полный аналог chmod для NTFS не возможен.

Comment: Винду я плохо знаю (самому интересен этот вопрос) и тем не менее 

    C:\Users\avp>ls -l c:\
    total 4293954113
    drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Aug 19  2012 Recycle.Bin
    -rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group      328231 Jul 11 17:18 11072013563.jpg
    -rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group          87 Sep  4  2011 CIR.log
    drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Dec  8 12:55 Config.Msi
    drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Oct  3 21:24 CopySamsungH
    ... и т.д. ...


`ls` из `UnixUtils` что-то выводит.

Так что, я бы не был столь категоричен.

Comment: мне кажется, что он нагло симулирует. Там есть права, отличные от `-rw-rw-rw-`, `-rwxrwxrwx` и `drwxrwxrwx`? Думаю, может быть ещё найдется такое `----------` (ну или что то в этом стиле).

Comment: @avp http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html

Answer (score 3):

Разграничение прав есть и в *nix и в окнах. Группа - глобальная категория с предустановленным списком прав, каждый пользователь в той группе может иметь привилегии ниже установленных прав группы, но не выше их(Нельзя создать полноприводного админа в группе "Гости").

Группы избавляют от рутинной работы вроде такой: надо создать 6 админов. 
Путь без групп: создаем пользователя проставляем все права(овер9000 галочек, птичек, записей) и так 6 раз. Повесится можно уже на 3м.

Путь с группой: Создать группу, проставить овер9000 птичек и т.д. и т.п., создать 6 пользователей в этой группе. Все.

Второй вопрос: 
Возвращается указатель на родительскую группу, к которой принадлежит пользователь, что не ясно?

Answer (score 0):

это никак к винде не относится, у нее такого нет

а задача у вас скорее всего простая: ставить или удалять доступ на чтение и все )))

Answer (score 0):

Толком помочь не могу, но часто пользуюсь командой attrib

```
[Rijen2@Rijen-PC C:\cygwin\home\rijen]# attrib /?
Вывод и изменение атрибутов файлов.ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A ] [+S | -S] [+H | -H]      [диск:] [путь] [имя_файла]
        [/S] [/D]]

  +   Установка атрибута.
  -   Снятие атрибута.
  R   Атрибут "Только чтение".
  A   Атрибут "Архивный".
  S   Атрибут "Системный".
  H   Атрибут "Скрытый".
  [диск:] [путь] [имя_файла]
      Указание файла или набора файлов для обработки.
  /S  Обработка файлов с указанными именами в текущей папке
      и во всех ее подпапках.
  /D  Обработка и файлов, и папок.
```

А права для групп/пользователей устанавливаются через локальную политику аудита. Возможно через WinAPI это делать легче чем ручками, но не все версии окон поддерживают политики.

Comment: Да, полный аналог невозможен =) Пунктик "Выполнение" не существует.
А что-то вида ASHrwrwrw теоретически можно сделать =)

Comment: это не права доступа а атрибуты файла

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло, Я знаю =) Про права доступа я написал ниже листинга.

Answer (score 0):

решаема через Power Shell [(пример)](http://sergeyvasin.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/powershell-acls/)

Answer (score 0):

Есть книга автор Джонсон  Харт, "Системное программирование в среде Microsoft Windows", там в одной из глав есть пример chmod на С+winapi.

Answer (score 0):

типичный ответ на вопрос почему "chmod не работает в Windows? Потому, что данная система прав реализована в *unix"... А вот если рассмотреть в контексте сборки WAMP и LAMP...

Как известно Apache+MySQL+PHP для винды существует, и это при всяких нюансах от разницы в слэшах и т.п, казалось бы тривиальных вещей. А вот CHMOD? Да, не может php скажем корректно читать chmod когда стоит на винде. Но факт остаётся фактом. Кидаем этот файл на сервер: и вуаля? Аттрибут присутсвует, хоть гоняй по 100 раз его туда сюда. CHMOD у файла всегда будет, просто восприимчивость не та у разных ОСей. Ну вот что бесит. Понятно винду под *nix не перепишешь под apache+php, но можно же было продумать способ эмуляции chmod, для обеспечения наиболее совместимости и портируемости контента...